# Intel XTU Undervolt settings not working between reboots

Tags: windows-10, boot, intel-core-i7, undervolting

If I undervolt my CPU/iGPU via the Intel Extreme Tuning Utility (XTU) on windows 10, it asks me to reboot to save the settings, I hit ok, the system reboots, and voila, I have an undervolted CPU.

Then the day ends, I shut down my system, start it up the next day and what do you know, the undervolt settings aren't there anymore. So I apply them again, reboot and presto.

The problem is, I don't want to have to restart my computer every single time I turn it on to get my undervolt (vital for this CPU, stupid laptop manufacturers), much less do I want to risk forgetting it.

So far to circumvent this I've tried to apply this batch script with heightened privileges on login:

```
echo off
rem taskkill /F /IM "perftune.exe"
sc start XTU3SERVICE
timeout 5
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Extreme Tuning Utility\Client\XTUCli.exe" -t -id 34 -v -0.150
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Extreme Tuning Utility\Client\XtuCLI.exe" -t -id 83 -v -0.050
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Extreme Tuning Utility\Client\XtuCLI.exe" -t -id 79 -v -0.150
sc stop XTU3SERVICE
exit
```

It did nothing for my problem, and it was the only potential solution I've found, besides maybe setting it in the bios (not an option in mine). I'm already out of ideas, how do I force these settings to stick between all reboots/shutdowns?

Answer (score 2):

XTUCli.exe is removed in the 6.5 version of XTU. So all the batch scripts are not working anymore. You could try downgrading

Comment: That does explain why the scripts aren't working :) but using an older version is ultimately a workaround, not a proper solution, I'd like to see an answer with a solution for the latest version. Upvoted for valuable answer though, welcome to superuser!

Comment: You could use ThrottleStop instead, and set it to start on boot. Additionally, if you enable Fast Startup instead of a cold boot every morning, or chose to hibernate your PC at night, it should save your XTU settings, I think. One of the few things where Fast Startup actually comes in handy.

Comment: @Ramhound indeed, just like I said.